# unity smooth 2D horizontal transform

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Currently, I have a script for mobile that simply has a ball on the screen, and when you touch to the left of the ball, it moves left, and when you touch to its right, it moves right. However, when it moves, it is not smooth unless I lower the float for how much it moves by (which causes it to be too slow). How can I maintain a fast translation speed whilst the movement being smooth?

```
if (Input.touchCount > 0)
    {
        Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0);

        var point = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(touch.position.x, touch.position.y,
            transform.position.z - Camera.main.transform.position.z));

        float dx = point.x - transform.position.x;
        if (point.x < transform.position.x)
        {
            //transform.Translate(-15f * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0);

            transform.Translate (dx * (1 - Mathf.Pow (0.5f, Time.deltaTime / halfWayTime)), 0, 0);


        }
        else if (point.x >= transform.position.x + 0.5f)
        {
            //transform.Translate(15f * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0);
            transform.Translate (dx * (1 - Mathf.Pow (0.5f, Time.deltaTime / halfWayTime)), 0, 0);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
float targetX;
const float halfWayTime = 0.1f;

void Update () {
    float dx = targetX - transform.position.x;
    transform.Translate (dx * (1 - Mathf.Pow (0.5f, Time.deltaTime / halfWayTime), 0, 0);
}
```

This creates movement pattern which is fast at first, but slows down in the end, and targetX can be edited at any time. `halfWayTime` is the time for which the object will complete half of its path to target, if it's 0.1, then for 0.1s it will move 50% of the initial distance, for 0.2s - 75%, for 0.3s - 87.5% and so on.

By the way, you can modify this code to work with all coordinates:

```
void Update () {
    transform.position = Vector3.Lerp (
        target,
        transform.position,
        Mathf.Pow (0.5f, Time.deltaTime / halfWayTime)
    );
}
```

Comment: This works great, but only along the negative x axis, in the positive direction it seems to jump about a lot. Any idea why>

Comment: It should work in both directions in the same manner. @Mattattack , did you somehow change this code for opposite direction? If yes, you shouldn't. And please say how you set targetX, maybe it's there

Comment: For targetX, I worked out the point the users finger is touching, then worked it our relative to the world instead of the screen, I know this works fine. I have not changed the code for the other direction. I will update my question to show the new code.

Comment: Simply removing the unnecessary if statement has seemed to got it working! Thanks for all the help!